# prevent flask session from reloading on ajax call

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-session

So, I am trying to make a flask session expires after a certain amount of time.

After a user login is validated I set `session.permanent = True`

In my config I have

```
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = timedelta(minutes=1)
SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST = False
```

and in my global before request:

```
if request.endpoint != 'static' and not request.is_xhr:
    session.modified = True
```

This works if the user's logged on my site and then closes the tab, after one minute the session is expired. However I have an AJAX request that is constantly running in background on all pages. If the user is in any of this pages the session never expires.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: session.modified = False on your ajax request handler should work for this. Not sure though!

Comment: Tried setting it at the beggining or end of the request, sadly it did not work. Thanks for trying though.